# Intrinsic rate of increase with Generalized Linear Models

Tags: generalized-linear-model, spss, poisson-distribution

I wonder if someone could help me with the following.
Target is to determine the intrisic rate of increase (log[lambda]) of wolves at certain plots (x) during certain period (y).

I have for example the following count data of wolves at the plot: 

Year (Counts)--> 2005 (1); 2007 (4); 2008 (2); 2011 (6)

...and also series were the years have zero's as counts, like

Year (Counts)--> 2005 (1); 2007(0); 2008 (0); 2009 (4); 2011 (6)

So as result I need the intrinsic rate of increase over the complete periods.

I know from prior calculations (as is stated in the description) that the intrinsic rate of increase is determined **as the slope of the counts to year of sampling** (= continuous trend). And the calculated log[lambda]'s are all between 1 and -1. I know that I need to use **GLM & Poisson error structure & log-link**. (this is all i know / I am able to deduct from the description)

But as I am new to this type of models I don't know where to start. Can I perform this for instance in SPSS. What is the first step I need to perform? Does anyone have a tip or link which steps I have to perform to get the intrinsic rate of increase? Which program? Can this be done within Excel and/or SPSS for instance?

Comment: and furthermore do I need to delete all fields with zero's as counts? (because the log function...)?

Comment: No, the zeros are data, and you should definitely not delete them! The log is not applied directly to the data!